# How could I power flexible oled screens with wearable power source and could I transmit data onto it with bluetooth via app

Tags: bluetooth, solar-cell, bluetooth-low-energy, oled, flexible

How could I power flexible oled screens with solar power and could I transmit data onto it with bluetooth via app?

Would this be possible? please can you help thank you

Comment: I have downvoted your question and voted to close of the grounds that it is too broad. Don't get discouraged - this sounds like a great project. Ask us specific, design related questions, one at a time, and show us what you have done, and we'll be more than happy to help. Welcome to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you'll need to break your design into separate subsystems and then integrate them.

Here are some of the subsystems you need to work on:

- Microcontroller interface with OLED display.
- Microcontroller interface with bluetooth.
- App for bluetooth interface
- Solar charger for battery (you'll need a battery)

Once you have figured out those 4 subsystems, you'll need to integrate them to create larger subsystems (e.g. using bluetooth to interface with OLED)

Edit: Just realized you want to make a wearable device. Keep in mind that the amount of energy that you gather depends on the size of the solar cells. Using might offset how fast your battery drains, but alone may not be enough to keep your system running.

Answer (score 1):

I can safely say that you will not manage a wearable system using solar power only in the near future. The amount of power you would require wouldn't be so high, but think of this - if it were so easy, i wouldn't have to plug in my cell phone at night, because it would simply be charged the next day.

Furthermore, I'm not sure what kind of resolution you're planning to use for the screen, but I'm absolutely positive that bluetooth will not handle wireless streaming high definition in its current state. Again, notice that these products don't exist - yet. And they might never, since Wifi based technologies to do this are built into the phone I am using to write this.

I need to tell you that this post needs to be closed based on the sites guidelines, as it is far too broad. But I also want to tell you to keep trying, because this sounds like a worthwhile endeavor. Good luck.

Comment: so im trying to ask a question for a product im developing so how do i ask the question without giving the exact idea away?

Comment: @Aires, this entire stack is devoted to solving electronic design issues, but you must come up with them one at a time. Get started on an actual design, start learning, laying out and simulating, and when you find an obstacle, post a question with everything relevant.